# How to Align text in specific path or way in android studio jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, text-alignment

[I want the text to be aligned in this image depicting fashion. How can i do it in jetpack compose android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7PsG.jpg)

[Here you can see while i'm typing text as input. I use the value to compose in text UI element. but the text is aligning not as expected when i tried to align. I was just experimenting

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp)){
                    Canvas(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    ) {
                        drawRect(color = Color.Yellow)
                    }
                    Text(text = text, fontSize = if(text.length >11){45.sp}else 55.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
.wrapContentSize(Alignment.BottomEnd).padding(end = 5.dp))
}
```

Any suggestions i really appreciate as I learning android.
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo4S7.gif)

I'm expecting text alignment starting at bottom end and when text length increase it should increase from right to left and for each line to be created above and moving in same right to left fashion there.

Comment: Apply textAlign = TextAlign.End